# How to maintain a property about trees using a Scala Collections TreeMap (or similar)

Tags: scala, tree

Since the scala RedBlack tree is no longer available in the scala collections, I'm having trouble figuring out how to maintain properties about tree in the nodes on a scala tree, as I need direct access to the tree rather than the encaspulated interface provided by the standard collections.

For example, I want a tree that maintains on each node a field x such that the function f holds for each node n such that

```
f(null) = 0
f(n) = n.x + f(n.left) + f(n.right)
```

Can I efficiently use a Scala standard library TreeMap for this or will I have to implement my own tree (currently doing this)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think you will be able to do this using TreeMap. You might want to just copy [the red black tree](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/5cb3d4ec14488ce2fc5a1cc8ebdd12845859c57d/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/RedBlackTree.scala) from scala collections and add a summary field.

Alternatively, you might want to use one of the tree-based collections that allow specifying a "measure". E.g.
https://github.com/Sciss/FingerTree

Or, you could use this horrible hack to add some summary data to the nodes of e.g. a TreeSet. Note the namespace scala.collection.immutable so you can access RedBlackTree from inside the utility.

```
package scala.collection.immutable

trait Summary[E, S] {
  def apply(v: E): S
  def empty: S
  def combine(a: S, b: S): S
  def combine3(a: S, b: S, c: S) = combine(combine(a, b), c)
}

object TreeSetSummarizer {

  private[this] val treeSetAccessor = classOf[scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet[_]].getDeclaredField("tree")
  treeSetAccessor.setAccessible(true)

  private def tree[K](set: TreeSet[K]): AnyRef = treeSetAccessor.get(set) match {
    case t: RedBlackTree.Tree[K, Unit] ⇒ t
    case _ ⇒ "null"
  }

  private type JFunction[T, R] = java.util.function.Function[T, R]

  def apply[K, S](implicit s: Summary[K, S]): (TreeSet[K] ⇒ S) = new TreeSetSummarizer[K, S]
}

class TreeSetSummarizer[K, S](implicit summary: Summary[K, S]) extends (TreeSet[K] ⇒ S) {
  import TreeSetSummarizer._

  // this should be a guava cache using weak keys to prevent memory leaks
  private val memo = new java.util.IdentityHashMap[AnyRef, S]()

  private val f: JFunction[AnyRef, S] = new JFunction[AnyRef, S] {
    def apply(t: AnyRef): S = t match {
      case t: RedBlackTree.Tree[K, Unit] ⇒ summary.combine3(apply0(t.left), summary.apply(t.key), apply0(t.right))
      case _ ⇒ summary.empty
    }
  }

  private def apply0(set: AnyRef): S =
    memo.computeIfAbsent(set, f)

  def apply(set: TreeSet[K]): S =
    apply0(tree(set))
}
```

Here is how you would use it

```
import scala.collection.immutable._

// create a large TreeSet
val largeSet = TreeSet(0 until 10000: _*)
// define your summary
implicit val s = new Summary[Int, Long] {
  def empty = 0L
  def apply(x: Int) = x
  def combine(a: Long, b: Long) = a + b
}
// define your summarizer. You need to keep the summarizer instance for
// having a performance benefit, since it internally stores summaries for
// tree nodes in an identity hash map
val summary = TreeSetSummarizer.apply[Int, Long]

// summarize something
println(summary(largeSet))

// summarize a modified set. This is fast because the summaries for tree
// nodes are being cached.
val largeSet1 = largeSet - 5000
println(summary(largeSet1))
```

Note that given the reflection and hashing overhead, this is probably best used for more computationally intensive summaries than a simple sum.

Update: I have now written a small library [persistentsummary](https://github.com/rklaehn/persistentsummary) to define persistent summaries for existing scala collections. This should do exactly what you want.

Comment: Yes, it's a shame. You got all these nice tree data structures, but no way to take advantage of the fact that they are trees. Except if you want to get really dirty...

Comment: I amended the answer with a dirty but perfectly working hack that will allow you to maintain a summary property of a large TreeSet

Comment: Appreciated but I've already hacked together my own treap so sadly I'm unable to use this :(